# Deciding which version of MySQL (5.7 or 8) I should use for Group Replication?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a production ready mysql with group replication, and wondering if there was a difference between v5.7 and v8.0 Group Replication implementation?

Keeping Group Replication and system stability in mind, would one version be preferred and/or more stable than the other?

Comment: I'm looking for stability over new features. Bit worried about 8.0 having new features/improvements which has risks of bug regressions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you have convinced me. I just finished setting up 5.7 but will reinstall with 8.0 now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask specifically about [Group Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication.html) and state that ***reliability is of great importance***, the [MySQL 8.0: New Features in Replication](https://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-8-0-new-features-in-replication/) post talks specifically about improvements with this functionality and MySQL 8.0. I've quoted and referenced the specific portions of this that talks about what I feel are important factors to be considered in making a determination.

> ## [MySQL 8.0: New Features in Replication](https://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-8-0-new-features-in-replication/)
>
> Recently a new technology, MySQL Group Replication, was released in
> MySQL 5.7, and later it was also included in MySQL 8. It is
> continuously improved either through bug fixing or new features in
> both MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8. But this is not the only new thing in
> MySQL 8. There is more.
>
> #### Relevant replication areas that have been improved in MySQL 8:
>
> - **Resiliency:** crash-recoverable DDLs in replication.
>
> #### Performance and Efficiency
>
> Making replication efficient and fast is also something that is
> continuously worked on. In MySQL 8, there are a set of features that
> enhance the replication applier pipeline, so that it is able to ingest
> more load coming in, faster and in a more efficient way. Here are the
> highlights:
>
> - **Transactions spend less time in the replication applier pipeline.** There is an improved synchronization mechanism between
>   receiver and applier threads, which translates into less contention
>   between receiver and applier threads. This enhancement allows both
>   receiver and applier threads to do more work in parallel instead of
>   serializing themselves in a lock that protects the relay log.
> - **More transactions are applied in parallel.**  Much improved parallel applier by relying on transaction WRITESETs (roughly the set
>   of rows changed). This also allows the applier to install changes in
>   parallel even for single threaded workloads coming in from
>   replication. There is much to say about this feature, but you can
>   learn more about the details here.
> - **Predictable and sustained replication throughput fine tuning flow control.** Flow control was also revised and improved. The user can
>   now fine tune a group replication cluster so that the impact of
>   imbalanced members is limited and the entire system converges to a
>   sustained throughput.
>
> #### Resiliency
>
> Metaphorically speaking, MySQL has had a brain transplant. It has now a new data dictionary, which among other
> improvements also brings in crash-recoverable dictionary changes.
> Roughly, this makes DDLs atomic and recoverable. This functionality is
> also extended to include binary log recoverability for DDLs.
>
> - **On recovery, recover my atomic DDLs too!** When the server is restarting after a crash, the binary log and the InnoDB synchronize on
>   to figure out which transactions to recover to bring both to a
>   consistent state. Now atomic DDLs recovery also takes into account the
>   contents of the binary log, so that metadata and the binary log is
>   consistent.
> - **On recovery, recover my atomic DDLs too… Oh, and my applier positions as well!** If a crash happens while a replication applier is
>   applying an atomic DDL, then recovery will make sure that the
>   replication positions are consistent with the metadata changes.
>
> [Source](https://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-8-0-new-features-in-replication/)

Comment: Nice answers guy,  and happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: Happy Thanksgiving @Tim_Stewart!!!